# Nightwatch.JS unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, nightwatch.js

Hey I'm new to Nightwatch.js, I've been trying to get `browser.getElementSize` to work with my Nightwatch.js setup. Every time I try run the test, I get errors saying W3C doesn't like it.

I've tried to add w3c equals false to my config file, but no matter where I put it, it still doesn't work.

```
desiredCapabilities: {
  browser: "chrome",
  "javascriptEnabled" : true,
  "acceptSslCerts" : true,
  name: "Chrome-[Nightwatch] Sample Test",
  chromeOptions: { w3c: false }
}
```

After running my test I get the following error messages:

> Error while running .getElementSize() protocol action: unknown
>   command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode

and

> TimeoutError: An error occurred while running .getElementSize()
>   command on <#bedrooms>:

Comment: Hey again Dalton, I think you haven't setup your environment properly for some reason, as `.getElementSize()` method is working just fine. Also, this is not the correct way to go to check images loaded (_feels like scratching the left ear with the right arm_). Also, you didn't take into account different resolutions for different viewports. 

Anyways, I think I can only help you if we both start from a working model: check [THIS](https://github.com/ChrisZie/nightwatch-boilerplate) project out. Clone it, follow README.md, then test the answers I gave you on the other question & this command.

Comment: Hey this worked using that boilerplate, thank you!
Now im just trying to edit the reports that it generates. I got it working on my other set up using handlebars but i cant get it working with this new set up

Comment: Dalton, can you please open up a separate question for that so I can tackle it there? I didn't try that reporter, so I would have to do some research for that. Also, please try the answer I specified on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58490607/how-to-check-full-page-for-broken-images-using-nightwatch-js) question you opened and consider closing it and accepting my answer.

Comment: Also make a habit of closing questions & accepting (_click check next to answer_) good answers. Thanks!